# How to paralellise a Tree traversal using OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, tree, openmp

I am writing code that traverses a tree of person objects. The person object contains an index(uniqueId), numberOfFriends and friends (array of person objects). I want to use openMp in order to speed up the process as the number of nodes is very large. I have tried to use tasks but unfortunately it was only running on thread 0. The code is below:

```
void less_find_reachable_recursive_para(struct person * current, int steps_remaining,
              int * reachable, int totalSteps) {
   int stepsTaken = totalSteps-steps_remaining;
   int num_known;
   reachable[person_get_index(current)] = stepsTaken;
   struct person * acquaintance;
   // now deal with this person's acquaintances

   if ( steps_remaining > 0 ) {
   num_known = person_get_num_known(current);
   for ( int i = 0; i < num_known; i++ ) {
  acquaintance = person_get_acquaintance(current, i);
  if(reachable[person_get_index(acquaintance)] > stepsTaken ||reachable[person_get_index(acquaintance)] ==0 && person_get_index(acquaintance) != 0){
   //#pragma omp task
    less_find_reachable_recursive_para(acquaintance, steps_remaining-1, reachable, totalSteps);
    }
  }
```

}
}

Comment: How are you calling `less_find_reachable_recursive_para`? It must be in a parallel region for the `task` construct to execute in parallel.

Comment: Adding `#pragma omp parallel` before calling the function in the parent function does solve this thank you! However it is still slower than my non parallelized version. Is this because I am making too many tasks?

Comment: Don't forget `#pragma omp single` inside the parallel region, otherwise you will be running `N` identical traversals in parallel where `N` is the number of threads. Also, limiting the recursion level at which tasks are still created, will speed things up. The OpenMP overhead grows with the accumulated size of the search front.

Comment: That is great, Thanks! My program has sped up considerably